# django messages syntaxerror useing f string

Tags: python, django

i am trying to send a message to the user of my site when they register i used django message import but i did not work

here is my views.py code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import cooking
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout, authenticate
from django.contrib import messages

# Create your views here.



def homepage(request):
    return render(request=request,template_name='main/home.html',context={"cooking": cooking.objects.all})

def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.succees(request, f"new account created: {username}")#error on this line

            login(request, user)
            return redirect("main:homepage")
        else:
            for msg in form.error_messages:
                messages.error(request, form.error_messages[msg])
    form = UserCreationForm
    return render(request,"main/register.html",context={"form":form })
```

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Answer (score 1):

`f-strings` have been introduced in Python 3.6, you're probably using a previous version.

If you really wanted to use them you could install [`future-fstrings`](https://github.com/asottile/future-fstrings) but I'm not sure it's worth.

A probably better solution would be to either upgrade Python to a version greather or equal to 3.6 or use one of the alternative formatting options:

- `"new account created: {}".format(username)`
- `"new account created: %s" % username`